# MySQL, PHPMyAdmin- Handling Link Table Index

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a link table with three columns `process id`, `elt`, `idx`.
I want to write into it with `process id` and `elt` only - i.e.

```
Insert into table(process id, elt) values (123, "abc")
```

So that the idx auto increments with respect to process id:

(123, abc, 1) , (123, def, 2) , (124, abc, 1) etc.

Can anyone advise how to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Simply applying auto increment seems to apply to the whole table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be done manually or using a before insert trigger, but could possibly leave you with a duplicate idx (maybe locking the table within the trigger could prevent this).

I don't believe you can use an after insert trigger (can't update the table in that).

Comment: Thanks- I think that I will work with a new table altogether and configure it as I need it...